# clone and the CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID flag

Tags: c, linux, clone, system-calls

I need some help with the clone() system call.
I'm trying to use it with the flag CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID but I cant see any change in the value of the field I specify as argument.
Here it is a simple code:

```
int the_child(){
   exit(0);
}
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    pid_t child_id = 99;
    printf("child %p\n",child_id);

    clone((int (*)(void *))the_child,
          NULL,
          CLONE_VM | CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID | SIGCHLD,
          NULL, NULL,NULL, child_id);

    sleep(1);
    printf("child %p\n",child_id);
 }
```

However when the two printf display always 99, What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `child_id` through value. You should pass it as a pointer.

[This is where](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/fork.c#754) the clearing of `tid` takes place inside the kernel

```
/*
 * We don't check the error code - if userspace has
 * not set up a proper pointer then tough luck.
 */
put_user(0, tsk->clear_child_tid);
```

Can you see the comment warning of the same ? :)

[See this blog](http://blog.andrewvc.com/fork2-is-dead-long-live-fork-i-mean-clone2) where they are tracking the arguments to `clone` system call through `strace`

**EDIT** : Adding from our discussion in comments, `child_stack` can be zero for `sys_clone` system call but not for the library function `clone()`

Comment: I edited the code and used `&child_id` in the `clone` but nothing changed :(

Comment: My bad. Seams that I can not `NULL` value for the child stack.

Comment: @Federico Actually for the `sys_clone` system call, on top of which is the library function `clone` is implemented, `child_stack` can be zero. May be not when you are using the library function. After you supplied the stack appropriately for the child, what happened to the `tid` clearing functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you allocate memory (`malloc()`) before creating clone?